# Changing NaN to 0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, report-builder2.0

This is my current expression below which works fine until the answer is zero and then I am presented with NaN in my report.

`=sum(IIF(Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Not applicable" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Limited to item" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "room of origin" , 1, 0),"ADF")   / sum(fields!total.value,"ADF")`

I have tried using 'Is Nothing' in various ways, one example below, but can't get it work, would like some help please.

`=IIF(IsNothing(sum(Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Not applicable" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Limited to item" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "room of origin" , 1, 0),"ADF"))   / sum(fields!total.value,"ADF")  , 0, sum(Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Not applicable" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Limited to item" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "room of origin" , 1, 0),"ADF")   / sum(fields!total.value,"ADF")`

Answer (score 0):

Try below expression

```
 = IIF(IsNothing(Fields!RestrictedTo.value) and IsNothing(sum(fields!total.value,"ADF")) ,
    0,sum(IIF(Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Not applicable" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Limited to item" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "room of origin" , 1, 0),"ADF")/ sum(fields!total.value,"ADF")
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't work, telling me the field 'RestrictedTo' isn't specifying a dataset aggregate

Comment: I would say try one expression at a time meaning something like this,
`IF(IsNothing(Fields!RestrictedTo.value) and and IsNothing(sum(fields!total.value,"ADF"), true,false)`

Answer (score 0):

Go to report properties, and in Code tab type in:

Function Divide(Numerator as Double, Denominator as Double)

If Denominator = 0 Then
Return 0
Else
Return Numerator/Denominator
End If
End Function

Then in your report enter the following expression:

=Code.Divide(sum(IIF(Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Not applicable" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "Limited to item" or Fields!RestrictedTo.value = "room of origin" , 1, 0),"ADF")   / sum(fields!total.value,"ADF"))